# Would a "Common Denominator" phonology be too simple (or even non-existent)?

Tags: phonology, auxlangs

Many languages have sounds that are very hard to pronounce to certain speakers.

For example, the French "R" sound is hard for English speakers. What if we have a language that accepts many variations of a word so that it's still accepted even if it sounds a little different?

Another example, Japanese phonology does not distinguish between L and R. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4MsJHn-lRA) shows how incredible it is.

I think this is a similar concept to how languages can change how many things you can notice, [even colors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1-WuBbVe2E) can be hard to distinguish if you don't have a word for it.

But if you're coming from a language that does distinguish between the sounds, it will be easier for you to pronounce words of a language that doesn't distinguish it. I think that the Japanese L/R sound is easy because they don't care which one you pronounce, it sounds the same to them.

However, I know it might cause the language phonology to be too simple, which will cause [very long words](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/strategies-for-dealing-with-limited-simple-phonologies). I have not studied every single language in the world. But is really that bad if we are to create this "combined phonology?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed possible to create a non-trivial ‘lowest common denominator’ phonology. I know because I made one myself a while ago. For consonants, I took the 10 most common segments from [PHOIBLE](https://phoible.org/parameters) disregarding voicing distinctions:

/m n/
/p t k/
/s h/
/l j w/

Vowels are much easier: /a i u/ is suitably lower-common-denominator, and is widely attested.

Comment: It is worth noting that /h/ is not phonemic in a couple major world languages, namely French and Spanish (though in some dialects of the latter it's a word-final allophone of /s/).

Answer (score 7):

There are both natlangs and conlangs with extremely simple phonologies.

For natural languages, [Central Rotokas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotokas_language) holds the record for the smallest attested inventory of consonant phonemes (6).

For a conlang, you may want to look at [Toki Pona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toki_Pona#Phonology_and_phonotactics) with an inventory of 14 phonemes: 9 consonants and 5 vowels. Toki Pona has some speech community and is more than just a *Plansprachenprojekt*.

These examples show that languages with  extremely minimal phonologies are feasible. Yes, words and phrases become longer, but this is compensated by a higher speech rate.

Comment: With fewer phonemes you can be more careless (ie faster) with pronunciation, as there is more redundancy -- you need to distinguish between fewer elements. Hence the faster speech rate. Don't worry if you slur your vowels if /a/ and /e/ are the same anyway...